# XQuery - sum of values of element value in unbounded structure

Tags: xquery

I am trying to get a sum of values of specific field from the below structure but look like its not working as I am getting error as expected zero or one value but got two or more.

```
 <v4:CalculateResponse xmlns:v4="http://services.xx.net/mm/va">
       <v4:CalculateResponseSizeType>
          <v4:CalculateCCs>
             <v4:Container>
                <v4:GrossBookedWeight>31.6</v4:GrossBookedWeight>
                <v4:NetPredictedWeight>50</v4:NetPredictedWeight>
                <v4:GrossPredictedWeight>53.6</v4:GrossPredictedWeight>
                <v4:TypeOfWeightUsed>P</v4:TypeOfWeightUsed>
             </v4:Container>
             <v4:Container>
                <v4:GrossBookedWeight>31.6</v4:GrossBookedWeight>
                <v4:NetPredictedWeight>50</v4:NetPredictedWeight>
                <v4:GrossPredictedWeight>53.6</v4:GrossPredictedWeight>
                <v4:TypeOfWeightUsed>B</v4:TypeOfWeightUsed>
             </v4:Container>
             <v4:Container>
                <v4:GrossBookedWeight>31.6</v4:GrossBookedWeight>
                <v4:NetPredictedWeight>50</v4:NetPredictedWeight>
                <v4:GrossPredictedWeight>53.6</v4:GrossPredictedWeight>
                <v4:TypeOfWeightUsed>B</v4:TypeOfWeightUsed>
             </v4:Container>
             <v4:Container>
                <v4:GrossBookedWeight>31.6</v4:GrossBookedWeight>
                <v4:NetPredictedWeight>50</v4:NetPredictedWeight>
                <v4:GrossPredictedWeight>53.6</v4:GrossPredictedWeight>
                <v4:TypeOfWeightUsed>P</v4:TypeOfWeightUsed>
             </v4:Container>
      </v4:CalculateCCs>
   </v4:CalculateResponseSizeType>
   <v4:Status>P</v4:Status>
   <v4:StatusCode>1000</v4:StatusCode>
</v4:CalculateResponse>
```

I have tried summing these values using below function but look like its only onpecting one value.

```
<Weight>
        {
        sum(
            data($calculateResponse1/*:CalculateResponseSizeType/*:CalculateCCs/*:Container[data(*:TypeOfWeightUsed) = "B"]/*:GrossBookedWeight), 
            data($calculateResponse1/*:CalculateResponseSizeType/*:CalculateCCs/*:Container[data(*:TypeOfWeightUsed) = "P"]/*:GrossPredictedWeight)
        )

    }
</Weight>
```

here calculation is simple, say if TypeOfWeightUsed = 0 then I want to use GrossPredictedWeight element value or if TypeOfWeightUsed = B then I want to use GrossBookedWeight.

we can have multiple container in a structure.

Pls suggest what is wrong with above syntex.

Comment: Could you paste in the exact error you're getting? Also, it might be helpful to know what implementation of XQuery you're using.

Answer (score 1):

> here calculation is simple, say if TypeOfWeightUsed = 0 then I want to use GrossPredictedWeight element value or if TypeOfWeightUsed = B then I want to use GrossBookedWeight.

You can use FLOWR expression with the help of `if else` construct to get all numbers needed for doing the `sum()` :

```
<Weight>
{
    sum(
        for $c in $calculateResponse1/*:CalculateResponseSizeType/*:CalculateCCs/*:Container
        return 
            if($c/*:TypeOfWeightUsed = "B") then $c/*:GrossBookedWeight
            else $c/*:GrossPredictedWeight
    )
}
</Weight>
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/80d6a9d7f51ed1a0c0e9edbec49a28af)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<Weight>170.4</Weight>
```

Answer (score 1):

When the sum() function has two arguments, the second argument provides a value to be used as the result when the first argument is an empty sequence. (This is a clumsy way of dealing with the fact that without static type checking, the sum() function cannot distinguish an empty sequence of doubles from an empty sequence of durations, and you don't really want an integer-zero result when you are summing durations).

You have called the function with two arguments, but I think you want both sequences to be regarded as inputs to be summed. Just add another pair of parentheses to make it a single argument: replace `sum(x, y)` by `sum((x, y))`.

The reason you got an error is that the second argument, if supplied, must be a singleton value, not a sequence.